# Pattern: with a text_field allows an empty string through in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I am using a text_field to enter 24 hour time on a form. The regular expression works for everything but and empty string. Why?

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_tod %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start_tod,
      value: (tod_to_str(@availability.start_tod) || '00:00'),
      pattern: '([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[:|\.][0-5][0-9]|24[:|\.]00',
      title: '00:00 to 24:00' %>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean params[:start_tod] comes as empty string?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an empty string or if it's nil. Either way, the time is the job start time and it must be entered or the entire job record is invalid.

Comment: This seems more like a regex question. Have you tried playing with [Rubular](http://rubular.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To check the 24 hour text format, as `HH:mm` you can use the following regex:

`([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]`

in the first part you have one group, that will handle hours separetely, with rules for hours started with 0 and 1. The last part if for the numbers.

You should also add some validation on your model, based on the same regexp, and decide if you want to save an empty string or a nil value when the user don't fill anything.